# parse xml to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml

I have a XML feed from which I need to parse some of it and store it into MySQL table, but I'm facing a new kind of XML (I'm not good at this)
Here is the XML I'm getting which i'm opening using `simplexml_load_file` from this address:
[It's a pubmed journal publication](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=22064119) I need to store authorlist and some other, but with a hint on how to access it I can manage.
Thanks a lot

```
  SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
 [DocSum] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Id] => 22064119
        [Item] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2011 Dec
                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => EPubDate
                                [Type] => Date
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Clin Nucl Med
                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => AuthorList
                                [Type] => List
                            )

                        [Item] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Jackson TA
                                [1] => Choong KW
                                [2] => Eng JA
                                [3] => McAneny D
                                [4] => Subramaniam RM
                                [5] => Knapp PE
                            )

                    )

                [4] => Knapp PE
                [5] => F-18 FDG PET/CT Imaging of Endogenous Cushing Syndrome.
                [6] => 36
                [7] => 12
                [8] => e231-2
                [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => LangList
                                [Type] => List
                            )

                        [Item] => English
                    )

                [10] => 7611109
                [11] => 0363-9762
                [12] => 1536-0229
                [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => PubTypeList
                                [Type] => List
                            )

                        [Item] => Journal Article
                    )

                [14] => PubMed - in process
                [15] => ppublish
                [16] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => ArticleIds
                                [Type] => List
                            )

                        [Item] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 10.1097/RLU.0b013e3182336360
                                [1] => 00003072-201112000-00044
                                [2] => 22064119
                                [3] => 22064119
                                [4] => 22064119
                            )

                    )

                [17] => 10.1097/RLU.0b013e3182336360
                [18] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => History
                                [Type] => List
                            )

                        [Item] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2011/11/09 06:00
                                [1] => 2011/11/09 06:00
                                [2] => 2011/11/09 06:00
                            )

                    )

                [19] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => References
                                [Type] => List
                            )

                    )

                [20] => 1
                [21] => 0
                [22] => Clinical nuclear medicine
                [23] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => ELocationID
                                [Type] => String
                            )

                    )

                [24] => 2011 Dec;36(12):e231-2
            )

    )

 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run an XPath on the object like this: `$xml->xpath('/DocSum/Item/3/Item');`

Comment: Solved it this way:

    $xmlDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDOM->loadXML($xml);

    $item = $xmlDOM->getElementsByTagName("Item");

    for ($i=0; $i<$item->length; $i++) {
    $nada[] = $item->item($i)->nodeValue;

    }


    $todo = explode("\n", $nada[3]);

Thanks.